# Ruby HTTP request always returns 403 response (too many requests). Works in Postman/browser

Tags: ruby, http

I am trying to write a simple function which would easily extract the contact information from a classified listing.

### Background

The URL I'm looking at is
https://www.idealista.pt/imovel/27542922/

Looking through the developer tools in Chrome, I see that it makes a GET request to this URL. https://www.idealista.pt/pt/ajax/listingController/adContactInfoForListing.ajax?adId=27542922

If I make a GET request in Postman or just copy the second URL into Chrome I get a JSON containing various details.

### My code

(Ruby)

```rb
  uri = URI('https://www.idealista.pt/pt/ajax/listingController/adContactInfoForListing.ajax?adId=27542922')
  foo = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  JSON.parse(foo)
```

### The problem

The response is a 403 with a body saying that the system has detected that many requests have been made in a short period of time.

I can replicate this in Postman by doing seven or eight consecutive requests, but then if I wait a minute or two before trying again I get back to seeing the JSON.

Through Ruby it happens straight away.

### What I've tried

I've tried copying some or all of the temporary headers created by Postman into my request in Ruby but I still get the same error or 404

```
User-Agent - PostmanRuntime/7.22.0
Accept - */*
Cache-Control - no-cache
Postman-Token - 6c68a9eb-83d5-4724-9f41-3fc51971db9f
Host - www.idealista.pt
Accept-Encoding - gzip, deflate, br
Cookie - userUUID=c017919a-6115-4905-95b3-5d949c6fb447; _pxhd=34ed938caca242bf6050147e1514cda07b704cc7681245a4beec5a64e0a5cf66:d4f21381-522a-11ea-a954-6f59910ff05b; SESSION=887b6dbc-78a4-4abd-9600-7ce401507331; WID=15a353ca7aab3446|XlEN6|XlEN4
Connection - keep-alive
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to use a proxy, and chanfe the ip

Comment: Change it how? And to what?